# word document {tokens} replacement using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to read a .doc file and find tokens like {name}, {phone}, {address} etc. now display tokens with text box and allow user to replace by inserting original data. so that .doc file will replace with actual data.how to do this using php? the color, fonts, and style of .doc should not be changed.
thanks....

Comment: show some code! What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

This will be very tricky if you are using the old style Word documents. The new Word documents are saved in a some sort of Zip archive and therefore are much easier to edit.

You can extract this files and with some knowledge of the contents and Word WSDL you can edit the contents of the file.

Much easier is to make use of the [PHPDocX Library](http://www.phpdocx.com/). We are using it in a project and works like a charm. Only disadvantage is that it only works with .docx files.

Comment: i downloaded PHPDocx and executed the examples. but createHTML.php (examples\easy\createHTML.php) is not working. is it possible to convert a .doc or .docx file to thml? so that i replace the token in html itself and convert it to .doc or .docx again. thanks.......

Comment: Tak a look at the documentation: http://www.phpdocx.com/documentation/generate_xhtml_from_word_document

Comment: thanks for ur answer. i v working with PHPDOCX free version. but the createHTML.php and generateXhtml.php both are showing error like "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading". plz help...